# How would I use JS keydown function to toggle a class and activate/deactivate an animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've currently written all of my code in purely HTML and CSS however I'm now looking to change the CSS from using :hover to transition the elements and instead I want to use a javascript "keydown" function so when the key is pressed the animation starts and stays open until the key is lifted up, the animation then has a 3second timer and reverts back to its original position.

I'm really stuck as to whether I should just convert the entire animation into JS or just remove the ":hover" and toggle the class?

```css
.tempbg {
        background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 1920px 1080px;
}

.masscont {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    position: sticky;
    top: 50px;
    left: 1725px;
    width: 260px;
    height: 85px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .237);
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    left: -95px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 85px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0%;
    border-top-left-radius: 0%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    transition: width 2.2s cubic-bezier(0.24, 0.26, 0.63, 0.93);
}

.container:hover {
    width: 260px;
}

#voice {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    bottom: -00px;
    width: 107.5px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
}

.fa-microphone {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 69px;
    bottom: 25px;
    color: #525151;
    font-size: 38px;
 }

.fa-microphonebg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -60px;
    width: 121px;
    height: 85px;
    background-image:
  radial-gradient(circle at 0% 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50px, #fff 51px);
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: left 1.7s ease-in-out;
}

.masscont:hover #fa-microphonebg {
    left: 140px;
}

#boxVoice {
    background: rgb(180, 180, 180);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    height: 27px;
    width: 14.2px;
    left: 6.2px;
    bottom: 11px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3f31cfc768.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="tempbg">
<div class="masscont" id="masscont">
<div class="container" id="container">
<div id="voice">
</div>
<div class="fa-microphonebg" id="fa-microphonebg">
<i class="fas fa-microphone"><span id="boxVoice"></span></i>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add event listeners for `keypress` and `keyup` that add the current `:hover` classes and remove them. But modify those classes to no longer trigger on `:hover`.

```js
// Get refreences to the two tranistioned elements
let masscont = document.getElementById("masscont");
let container = document.getElementById("container");

// Set up a keypress event listener where the transition starts
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(){
  // Add the appropriate class to each element
  container.classList.add("containerMove");
  masscont.classList.add("masscontMove");
});

// Set up a keyup event listener where the transition ends
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
  // Remove the appropriate class to each element
  container.classList.remove("containerMove");
  masscont.classList.remove("masscontMove");
});
```

```css
.tempbg {
        background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 1920px 1080px;
}

.masscont {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    position: sticky;
    top: 50px;
    left: 1725px;
    width: 260px;
    height: 85px;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Change this class to not use a :hover pseudo-class */
.masscontMove #fa-microphonebg {
    left: 140px;
}

.container {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .237);
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    left: -95px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 85px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0%;
    border-top-left-radius: 0%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    transition: width 2.2s cubic-bezier(0.24, 0.26, 0.63, 0.93);
}

/* Change this class to not use a :hover pseudo-class */
.containerMove {
    width: 260px;
}


#voice {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    bottom: -00px;
    width: 107.5px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
}

.fa-microphone {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 69px;
    bottom: 25px;
    color: #525151;
    font-size: 38px;
 }

.fa-microphonebg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -60px;
    width: 121px;
    height: 85px;
    background-image:
  radial-gradient(circle at 0% 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50px, #fff 51px);
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: left 1.7s ease-in-out;
}

#boxVoice {
    background: rgb(180, 180, 180);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    height: 27px;
    width: 14.2px;
    left: 6.2px;
    bottom: 11px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3f31cfc768.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="tempbg">
<div class="masscont" id="masscont">
<div class="container" id="container">
<div id="voice">
</div>
<div class="fa-microphonebg" id="fa-microphonebg">
<i class="fas fa-microphone"><span id="boxVoice"></span></i>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: So this is absolutely perfect, thank you, if i wanted to add a specific keybind to the animation, for example using the letter "k", how would i go about it?

I thought this would be it, but im not sure:
```document.addEventListener("onkeydown", function(e){
    if (e.which == 75 || e.keyCode == 75) {
  container.classList.add("containerMove");
  masscont.classList.add("masscontMove");
    }
});```

Comment: instead of littering this post here is a JSFiddle with my full code. I've applied what you've written out here and tried adding to it. It works for the most part, it's just for some reason, some elements do not want to animate even though the "class" is being added and removed from each particular element. 

https://jsfiddle.net/Infamoose/ea7qch5d/34/

Comment: @Infamoose I have updated your Fiddle code to remove all the redundant `getElementById` lines and to combine the two `keyup` and `keydown` event handlers. I was able to isolate the problem to this line: `let walletbackg = document.getElementById("walletcont");`. I do see the `walletcont` element in your code, but perhaps your code is not valid and the element isn't being parsed in correctly. The update is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d8e6a14z/2/). Without that element in the picture, it does seem to work with both he `k` and `m` keys. Please consider marking my answer above as the answer.

Comment: I knew there was going to be a much neater way of coding the getElementByID, I just had no idea how to streamline it :P Thanks so much for all the help, I've applied the changes you've made to the original fiddle that I posted although I'm not sure if I've fixed the issue with the walletcont element or not because I don't see any problems on my end.

My final question is why does the keybind work in jsfiddle/code snipper but not when I open the index.html file in my browser? I've attached app.js via a script in the html so It should work?

Comment: @Infamoose I really couldn't say. You'll need to open your developers tools (F12) and look at the console tab to see what error(s) are being reported. Perhaps you didn't reference the file with the correct relative path? Also check the Network tab as this will tell you about any 404 errors (indicating whether your index page was able to connect to the app.js file).

Comment: I'm only getting this error ```"Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'cash' has already been declared".```I googled and someone mentioned it being an issue with the HTML file / an unclosed <div> but i've went over my html and nothing is wrong, i also used an online validator and have no issues.

Comment: I tried deleting that line for ```identifier "cash"``` and it moves the error to the next line for ```"bank" ```. I deleted that line also to see what would happen and then it gives me this error:

```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:67)
(anonymous) @ app.js:67
app.js:87 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:87)```

Comment: As far as I could see, `cash` was never a problem. It was `walletcont` that can't be found. But, you'll need to step through the code with the debugger to see where exactly things are going wrong. But, having an error confirms that the external code is being hit.

Comment: As a side note, you are importing two version s of JQuery, but not using it at all anyway.

Comment: I just took all the code from my Fiddle version and just copied it all into a single .html file and it works with no errors (although the `walletcont` line is still commented out).

Comment: It's okay, literally just figured it out, I'm importing this UI into a game via a mod using LUA etc. "cash" and "bank" were being used as variables already in amongst the rest of the code so I've renamed them slightly and it's all good to go. It now works in my browser environment, but still doesn't work in the game -_-'.

Thanks so much for all the help, time to crack on with getting it in the game now.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using jQuery I should work for binding the events and adding\removing the classes.

```
$('body').on('keydown', function() {
     $("element").addClass("class");
});

$('body').on('keyup', function() {
     $("element").removeClass("class");
});
```

Adding wait functions like that isn't really a great idea, but if you need to do it this will work:

```
function wait(ms){
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   var end = start;
   while(end < start + ms) {
     end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}
```

So to put it together

```
$('body').on('keydown', function() {
     $("element").addClass("class");
});

$('body').on('keyup', function() {
    wait(3000); 
    $("element").removeClass("class");
});
```

You can change the scope of the keyup\down bindings as well, if you don't want them body wide by selecting a different element.

Comment: Why do you think the OP is using JQuery? The question is not tagged with JQuery and there is no JQuery code being shown or requested.

Comment: Because it's literally in his code sample?

Edit: It was in the original code sample which was edited while I typed

Comment: Sorry, yeah I should've been a little more specific. I pasted my entire code to begin with which is part of a mod for a game (this is UI related) and that part uses jquery I  think. I'm purely working on the HTML CSS And am just adding JS for animation so i shortened my code before people raged at me :P.